# "Could Not Verify ST Device" when flashing STM32H747XIH6 over SEGGER J-link within STM32CubeIDE

Tags: stm32, jtag, stm32cubeide, j-link

Im trying to flash/debug a STM32H747XIH6 over J-link within STM32CubeIDE. One of the two cores, the CM7, flashes fine and i can enter the debugger. However when i try to flash the other core, the CM4, i get a popup with "Could Not Verify ST Device", and the console displays as shown below.

[image]

Any help or input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The debug probe is trying to access memory (`0x23000FD0`) that is out-of-bounds.

Check your project/debugging toolchain configuration. You probably specified the wrong MCU.

Memory Map:
[image]

Source: [STM32H747 Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0399-stm32h745755-and-stm32h747757-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the input! But unfortunetly its the correct board, an STM32H747XIH6 which is what i selected when i created the project (which i have done twice with the same result), and the other cpu flashes correctly. And i have tried to find what is at 0x23000FD0 but i can find nothing more specific that the image you sent.

Comment: Check if your toolchain is up-to-date. I've had issues in the past with erroneous toolchain configurations.

Comment: Another thing to check: setup a new minimal project (something like `void main() { return 0; }`) and see if this works. Maybe some not-so-obvious project option is broken.

Comment: How can i check my toolchain? I have done "check for updates" and found none. And this that i am trying now is a minimal project.

Comment: "Check for updates" usually should do the job.